# Maintaining 5V out from 2 Li-Ion Cells

Tags: power-supply

I'm designing a product that charges USB devices from its 2 internal Li-Ion cells that are in series, how can I maintain the 5V out across the output? The batteries I am using are 2x 3.7V 2250mAh Batteries: [datasheet](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/11db/0900766b811db0bc.pdf). How can I account for the discharge of the cells and still get 5V on my output?

Comment: With a device that drops the output dynamically based on a reference compared to the output. Such as a voltage regulator.

Comment: Yeah but take something like a 7805, the voltage of the 2 cells isn't enough to produce 5V out even when fully charged.

Comment: So then use a 1117-50.

Comment: But what about when the cells have a v_out about 4.2V this isn't sufficient to get 5V out of the regulator.

Comment: Are the cells in parallel or series?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams See edit.

Comment: If they're in series then letting them drop to 4.2V in the first place is a **Bad** Idea. Don't let them drop below 2.8V per cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a buck boost regulator like this: -

[image]

With any input voltage from 2.7V up to 15V it will produce a regulated 5V on the output. Efficiency depends on load current but it's most efficient range is when delivering currents from about 50mA to about 1 amp with an input voltage range from 2.7V to about 5V.

You have asked for a 5V output and I'm presuming that this will be suitable for your USB devices.

Comment: Thanks! This was the type of thing I was looking for but didn't know the technical name for it.